# How to see <private> data in iOS logs?

Tags: ios, logs

Looking at iOS 11 logs using Console.app in High Sierra, I see that many important bits of information are masked like this:

```
nsurlsessiond   Triggering periodic update to powerlog for client <private>
dasd    Trigger: <private> is now [<private>]
Yelp Reservations Map Extension [19 <private> <private>] start
```

which makes it hard to see what's really happening.  This happens on macOS too, and it can be changed with this command `sudo log config --mode 'private_data:on'`, as described [here](https://eclecticlight.co/2018/03/23/is-the-unified-log-private-or-a-vulnerability/).  How can I enable logging private data on iOS?

Answer (score 6):

There is no single setting that you can change for iOS logging as there is for macOS.

If you are running a beta version of iOS, the private log information seems to be collected, so that is one option.

The other option is to see if there is a profile on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/) that covers the logging you need.

Once you install the relevant profile you will see the previously `<private>` information appearing in the iOS console log.

In my case I was able to use the "Baseband" profile to enable caller id logging while working on a CallKit extension.

To disable the private logging you simply remove the profile from general settings on the device.

Answer (score 0):

If you're jailbroken, you can create a plist at `/Library/Preferences/Logging/com.apple.system.logging.plist` with a bool key `Enable-Private-Data` set to `TRUE`.

See https://github.com/EthanArbuckle/unredact-private-os_logs for more information.